# Best way to send all rows from sqlit3 database? (from server to client)

Tags: python, sockets, sqlite

I am building client-server program.
On the server I use a sqlite3 database to store all the users (with parameters like: registration time, is he admin etc..)
Now, I want to send all the rows to the client so I can show it in the client side in windows like this that I build:
[image]

And I am wondering, what is the best way to send this data?
I thought to put each row in tuple (the first value is username, second is reg date and etc)
and put all the tuples in list and send it via socket(by using cPickle.dumps so I could send the list via the socket) is it good? (for small amount of users)

Comment: For small amount of users you can dump it to JSON and send, no need to invent something complicated.

Comment: Note that pickle is Python-only - it will make it harder to serve clients written in other languages.

Comment: @vZ10, I have never used JSON but it sounds good solution, I will try it!
do you have any good tutorial or something that can help me? Thanks :)

Comment: @HughBothwell, Both my client and server written in python, but in the future it really  could be a problem, thanks!